# PayPal Sandbox Hosted Subscription Button (UK based)

Tags: paypal

The Non-hosted Subscription button in PayPal sandbox has a3, p3 and t3 hidden fields. The LIVE hosted button does not have these hidden fields. I would like to create a Sandbox version of the LIVE hosted Subscription button so that I can test a hosted subscription button before I go live.

thus I want a sandbox version of this:

```
<form action="http://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="xxxxxxxxxxx">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Instead of this:

```
<form action="http://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxx@xxx.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="GB">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="xxxxxxxxxx">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
        <!-- Set the terms of the regular subscription. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="19.95">
    <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="Y">
    <!-- Set recurring payments until canceled. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
    <!-- PayPal reattempts failed recurring payments. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://genial-diagram-711.appspot.com/guestbook" >
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hosted buttons don't expose the button details as compared to the non hosted buttons . You will only have the button id that is stored at PayPal's server and contains all the information like a3, p3, t3 . If you are looking for the hosted button for test environment then you need to login to your sandbox account and create the button from there.

You can follow the below steps to create the "_s-click" type buttons from your PayPal account :

Step1:

[image]

Step2 :

[image]

Step3 :

[image]

Comment: Eshan, I think you've misunderstood. I know I need to create the button via my sand box account. My problem (and my entire office here) is that we cannot see the link on the sandbox website to create a _s-xclick hosted button (only  _xclick-subscriptions).

Comment: Yes you can create the "_s-click" type buttons , you just need to select the "Save buttons at Paypal" option in step 2 while creating the button. I have updated my answer with the screen shots .